# Show that $\int_1^\infty x^n\sin(x+x^2)dx$ diverges, $n\ge1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How do I show that this improper integral diverges? I know certainly it is not always true that if $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, then $f(x)\to 0$. My intuition tells me this improper integral diverges because $x^n*\sin(x+x^2)$ oscillates between infinity and -infinity as $x\to \infty$. I am wondering if there is a nice way to prove it is divergent.

Comment: I'm interested in an example of an $f$ that has any finite integral $\int_a^\infty f(x)\, dx$ but doesn't converge to zero.

Comment: @Aruralreader $\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)dx$ converges, but $\cos(x^2)$ does not converge to 0.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We go to prove that the improper integral does not exist for each $n$.
Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $l=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx\in\mathbb{R}$
exists for some $n\geq1$, where $f(x)=x^{n}\sin(x+x^{2}).$ Define
$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx$. For $\varepsilon=1/4000$, there exists
$t_{0}>10$ such that $|F(t)-l|<\varepsilon$ whenever $t\geq t_{0}$.

Choose a sufficiently large $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists
$x_{2}>t_{0}+100$ satisfying that $x_{2}+x_{2}^{2}=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}.$
Let $x_1 \in(0,x_2)$ be such that $x_1 + x_1^2 = 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$. Such $x_1$ exists and is unique. For, let $g(x) = x + x^2$. Observe that $g(0) < 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $g(x_2) > 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$. By intermediate-value theorem, such $x_1$ exists. Since g is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, such $x_1$ is unqiue. We have that
$\frac{\pi}{4}=(x_{2}+x_{2}^{2})-(x_{1}+x_{1}^{2})=(x_{2}-x_{1})(1+x_{1}+x_{2})$
and hence $x_{2}-x_{1}=\frac{\pi}{4(1+x_{1}+x_{2})}<1$. This shows
that $x_{1}>x_{2}-1>t_{0}$. Moreover, $1-\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=\frac{\pi}{4(1+x_{1}+x_{2})x_{2}}$
and hence $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=1-\frac{\pi}{4(1+x_{1}+x_{2})x_{2}}>\frac{1}{2}$.

Observe that $\sin(x+x^{2})$ increases from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
to $1$ when $x$ increases from $x_{1}$ to $x_{2}$, so $f(x)\geq x_{1}^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
for all $x\in[x_{1},x_{2}]$. Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(x_{2})-F(x_{1}) & = & \int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}f(x)dx\\
 & \geq & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_{1}^{n}(x_{2}-x_{1})\\
 & = & \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\frac{x_{1}^{n}}{1+x_{1}+x_{2}}\\
 & \geq & \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}+x_{2}+x_{2}}.\\
 & > & \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\\
 & > & \frac{1}{1000}\\
 & = & 4\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, since $x_1,x_2 \in[t_0,\infty)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|F(x_{2})-F(x_{1})\right|\\
 & \leq & \left|F(x_{2})-l\right|+\left|F(x_{1})-l\right|\\
 & < & 2\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that $x$ goes to infinity I think it is fair to approximate it as the following:
$$\int_1^\infty x^n\sin(x^2)dx$$
Now we could split this up into regions, we know that $\sin(x)\ge0$ for $2k\pi\le x\le(2k+1)\pi$ where $k$ in an integer, so for the positive values of the $\sin$ function we have:
$$0\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_\limits\sqrt{2k\pi}^{\sqrt{(2k+1)\pi}}x^n\sin(x^2)dx\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int\limits_\sqrt{2k\pi}^\sqrt{(2k+1)\pi}x^ndx$$
Although I feel like to use this we could do with a much better lower limit than zero, so just a suggestion